# How to handle a read and write in Cloud Functions Firestore

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I am a little confused on how to refactor my code to read and write without the nested promises. Upon writing an object, if that object has a flag set, I want to update its "related" object with the new count. I have two problems.

1) Nested Promises from the read and then the write.
2) What am I supposed to return

```
exports.updateRelationshipCounts = functions.firestore
    .document('masterProduct/{nfCode}').onWrite((event) => {

    //on writing of record:

    var newProduct = event.data.data();
    if (newProduct.isGlutenFreeYN === 'Y') {
        console.log('Gluten Free');

        //Update GF count in the Brand Object:

        var db = admin.firestore();
        var docRef = db.collection("masterBrand").doc(newProduct.brandNFCode);
        var doc = docRef.get()
            .then(doc => {

                doc.glutenFreeCount = doc.glutenFreeCount + 1


                docRef.set(newProduct.brand)
                    .then(function () {
                        console.log("Document successfully written!");
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
                    });

                })
            .catch(err => {
                    console.log('Error getting document', err);
            })
    };

});
```

Plus it wants me to return something... nil?

Comment: Who wants you to return something?  The `.onWrite()` event handler?  None of the `.onWrite()` handlers in the [doc here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) show anything being returned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use chaining and eliminate some of the nesting.

```
exports.updateRelationshipCounts = functions.firestore
  .document('masterProduct/{nfCode}').onWrite((event) => {
    //on writing of record:
    var newProduct = event.data.data();
    if (newProduct.isGlutenFreeYN === 'Y') {
        console.log('Gluten Free');
        //Update GF count in the Brand Object:

        var db = admin.firestore();
        var docRef = db.collection("masterBrand").doc(newProduct.brandNFCode);
        docRef.get().then(doc => {
            doc.glutenFreeCount = doc.glutenFreeCount + 1
            return docRef.set(newProduct.brand);
        }).then(() => {
            console.log("document successfully written);
        }).catch(err => {
            // will log all errors in one place
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
});
```

Changes:

1. Chain at the top level rather than deeper and deeper nesting.
2. Return nested promises so they chain properly.
3. Consolidate error handlers to one `.catch()`